# Tkinter / pylab conflict?

Tags: python, plot, tkinter

I'm very new to Python but have started writing a few small scripts this week. I'm currently trying to write a simple program to plot some data. I'd like to do the following:

- ask the user to choose the data directory using a GUI
- for each file in the directory, make a plot
- close each plot with a mouse click and advance to the next plot

I've mostly gotten the program to work - I can choose the directory using `tkFileDialog.askdirectory`, then read in the data, make the plots and advance though them using a mouse click.

My problem is with the TK root window that opens with the `tkFileDialog`. If I use `withdraw()` the extra window doesn't open, but only the first plot will appear (a mouse click closes that plot but doesn't show the next one). If I don't use `withdraw()`, the extra window must be manually closed after the first plot to advance to the second.

I'm wondering if there is a way to choose the directory that will avoid displaying the extra window?

I'm attaching some sample code to show my thought process. This doesn't call the actual data but still reproduces the problem (you'll need to change the *.D* to some file type that you have in a directory):

```
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
import glob
import os
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog

##################################################
#define the mouse click event
##################################################
def moveon(event):
    close()

##################################################
#ask for the directory
##################################################
root = Tkinter.Tk()
#root.withdraw()
direc = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=root,initialdir="/",title='Please select a directory')
os.chdir(direc)
for files in glob.glob("*.D*"):

    ##################################################
    #Read in the data
    ##################################################
    #assume this reads x and y from each file
    x = [1, 2]
    y = [3, 4]

    ##################################################
    #loop though the plots 
    ##################################################
    fig = figure(1)
    plot(x,y)
    cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event',moveon)
    show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't seem to be using Tkinter after your file dialog, you could do `root.destroy()`
to close the Tk root window right after you have the user select a file.